# ERROR schema does not exist

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION analyzeTables()
  RETURNS INT AS $$
DECLARE
  v_rec information_schema.tables%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  FOR v_rec IN
  SELECT *
  FROM information_schema.tables mytable
  WHERE mytable.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'public'
        AND mytable.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
  ORDER BY mytable.table_name
  LOOP
    ANALYZE v_rec.table_name;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN 0;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM analyzeTables();
```

results in ERROR schema "v_rec" does not exist Where SQL statement `"ANALYZE v_rec.table_name"`.
As you can see I'm trying to analyze some tables within a function and it's not interpreting v_rec correctly it thinks it's a schema name when I trying to return the table name I want to analyze `i.e ANALYZE` fuel_station. Have tried with and without mytable alias and declared using both `%ROWTYPE` and `RECORD` makes no difference same error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try dynamic sql:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION analyzeTables()
  RETURNS INT AS $$
DECLARE
  v_rec information_schema.tables%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  FOR v_rec IN
  SELECT *
  FROM information_schema.tables mytable
  WHERE mytable.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'public'
        AND mytable.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
  ORDER BY mytable.table_name
  LOOP
    execute format('ANALYZE %I',v_rec.table_name);
  END LOOP;
  RETURN 0;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM analyzeTables();
```

use [format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT)

Comment: Hey Vao that worked perfectly thanks, as you can tell I'm a postgres noob but one who will now readup on format